# Typescript Format String to ##,##

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been going through this method to convert string to ##,## format. I was wondering is there a more simple way to achieve this?

```
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 })
    .format(Number(value.replace(',', '.')));
```

For example I want the below actual and expected format:

```
1 --> 1,00
12 --> 12,00
12,3 --> 12,30
12,34 --> 12,34
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Can you post the actual format and the expected format?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function format(num_as_string) { 
    return Number(num_as_string.replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(format('12'));
console.log(format('12,3'));
console.log(format('12,34'));
```

I hope I understood the question correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try **toLocaleString** method of js it will help you to achieve this format

visit this [url](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring_number.asp#:%7E:text=The%20toLocaleString()%20returns%20a,locale%20setup%20on%20your%20computer.) it will help you how to use it for different kind of formats

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the toFixed(2) javascript native function.

Example : parseFloat("9.2").toFixed(2) --> 9.20

Comment: Your answer could be improved by using better formatting and more detailed explanation. You can find information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Also note that the question uses comma as decimal separator, not dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out. I checked this for all your scenarios. This works fine.

```js
function formatNumber(num){
 return parseFloat(num.replaceAll(',','.')).toFixed(2).replaceAll('.',',');
}

console.log(formatNumber('12'));
console.log(formatNumber('12,3'));
console.log(formatNumber('12,34'));
```

Hope this answers your question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, by using DecimalPipe,

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'newp1';
  n1 = '1'; // 1 --> 1,00
  n2 = '12'; // 12 --> 12,00
  n3 = '13,2' // 12,3 --> 12,30
  n4 = '13,34' // 13,34 --> 12,34

  constructor(private decimal: DecimalPipe) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.transformValue(this.n1));
    console.log(this.transformValue(this.n2));
    console.log(this.transformValue(this.n3));
    console.log(this.transformValue(this.n4));
  }

  transformValue(num: string) {
    return (this.decimal.transform(num.replace(',', '.'), '1.2-2', 'en'))?.replace('.', ',');
  }
}
```

result:

```
1,00
12,00
13,20
13,34
```